# Post thumbnails from external urls dont appear in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Is there a way to make blogger fetch the external url from an image (that is already part of the post) so it can generate a thumbnail?

The template i had before generated thumbnails from both external or picasa urls, but i needed to change the template for a responsive one, and now the new one only chooses the images uploaded to picasa to generate thumbnails.

Here is part of the code for the recent posts list:

```html
<b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
                        <a class='wdxthumb' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
                          <img class='post-thumbnail' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.thumbnailUrl'/>
                        </a>
                        <b:else/>
                        <a class='wdxthumb' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
                          <img alt='no image' class='post-thumbnail' src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VnJqhx42r-c/UfFWlD-sF_I/AAAAAAAAAQI/rT3sYPba2dY/s271-Ic42/logo3.jpg'/>
                        </a>
                      </b:if>
```

Having the same problem with the related posts (in the post pages), this time with javascript:

```js
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var relnojudul = 0;
var relmaxtampil = 6;
var numchars = 100;
var reljudul = new Array();
var relurls = new Array();
var relcuplikan = new Array();
var relgambar = new Array();

function saringtags(g, h) {
  var e = g.split("<");
  for (var f = 0; f < e.length; f++) {
    if (e[f].indexOf(">") != -1) {
      e[f] = e[f].substring(e[f].indexOf(">") + 1, e[f].length)
    }
  }
  e = e.join("");
  e = e.substring(0, h - 1);
  return e
}

function relpostimgcuplik(h) {
  for (var e = 0; e < h.feed.entry.length; e++) {
    var g = h.feed.entry[e];
    reljudul[relnojudul] = g.title.$t;
    postcontent = "";
    if ("content" in g) {
      postcontent = g.content.$t
    } else {
      if ("summary" in g) {
        postcontent = g.summary.$t
      }
    }
    relcuplikan[relnojudul] = saringtags(postcontent, numchars);
    if ("media$thumbnail" in g) {
      postimg = g.media$thumbnail.url
    } else {
      postimg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VnJqhx42r-c/UfFWlD-sF_I/AAAAAAAAAQI/rT3sYPba2dY/s271-Ic42/logo3.jpg"
    }
    relgambar[relnojudul] = postimg;
    for (var f = 0; f < g.link.length; f++) {
      if (g.link[f].rel == "alternate") {
        relurls[relnojudul] = g.link[f].href;
        break
      }
    }
    relnojudul++
  }
}

function contains(a, e) {
  for (var f = 0; f < a.length; f++) {
    if (a[f] == e) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

function artikelterkait() {
  var v = new Array(0);
  var w = new Array(0);
  var x = new Array(0);
  var A = new Array(0);
  for (var u = 0; u < relurls.length; u++) {
    if (!contains(v, relurls[u])) {
      v.length += 1;
      v[v.length - 1] = relurls[u];
      w.length += 1;
      w[w.length - 1] = reljudul[u];
      x.length += 1;
      x[x.length - 1] = relcuplikan[u];
      A.length += 1;
      A[A.length - 1] = relgambar[u]
    }
  }
  reljudul = w;
  relurls = v;
  relcuplikan = x;
  relgambar = A;
  for (var u = 0; u < reljudul.length; u++) {
    var B = Math.floor((reljudul.length - 1) * Math.random());
    var i = reljudul[u];
    var s = relurls[u];
    var y = relcuplikan[u];
    var C = relgambar[u];
    reljudul[u] = reljudul[B];
    relurls[u] = relurls[B];
    relcuplikan[u] = relcuplikan[B];
    relgambar[u] = relgambar[B];
    reljudul[B] = i;
    relurls[B] = s;
    relcuplikan[B] = y;
    relgambar[B] = C
  }
  var r = 0;
  var D = Math.floor((reljudul.length - 1) * Math.random());
  var z = D;
  var q;
  var t = document.URL;
  while (r < relmaxtampil) {
    if (relurls[D] != t) {
      q = "<li class='news-title clearfix'>";
      q += "<a href='" + relurls[D] + "' rel='nofollow' target='_top' title='" + reljudul[D] + "'><div class='overlayb'></div><img src='" + relgambar[D] + "' /></a>";
      q += "<a class='relinkjdulx' href='" + relurls[D] + "' target='_top'>" + reljudul[D] + "</a>";
      q += "<span class='news-text'>" + relcuplikan[D] + "</span>";
      q += "</li>";
      document.write(q);
      r++;
      if (r == relmaxtampil) {
        break
      }
    }
    if (D < reljudul.length - 1) {
      D++
    } else {
      D = 0
    } if (D == z) {
      break
    }
  }
};

</script>
```

It happens also on the Popular list, on the Notícias and the 4 other widgets at the bottom of the homepage.
You can see the problem here: hondanewspot.com

Through out the internet the only explanation i can find is that blogger only generates thumbnail from images uploaded on to picasa and a few other. But the strange is that my other template worked fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by using `<data:post.firstImageUrl/>` tag instead of `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>` in the reccent post list code

```
<b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
    <a class='wdxthumb' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
        <img class='post-thumbnail' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl'/>
    </a>
    <b:else/>
    <a class='wdxthumb' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
        <img alt='no image' class='post-thumbnail' src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VnJqhx42r-c/UfFWlD-sF_I/AAAAAAAAAQI/rT3sYPba2dY/s271-Ic42/logo3.jpg'/>
    </a>
</b:if>
```

`<data:post.firstImageUrl/>` tag will return both Picasa hosted images as well as external images.

For the related post widget, you will have to make changes to the code to parse out the Image URL from the HTML response in case the image is not uploaded to Picasa storage